# Redshift reserved colume name "TIME"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
SELECT  customerID
FROM tableA
WHERE TIME= 2023-1-9
AND customerID Is Not Null;
```

In table A there is a column named as TIME and it stores date value.
as TIME is a reserved term in redshift , how can i call the column from the query?

there is a ERROR: syntax error at or near... from the above query.

Comment: calling a column TIME is not good design.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem:

```
SELECT  customerID
FROM tableA
WHERE "TIME"= 2023-1-9
AND customerID Is Not Null;
```

According to redshift docs, double quotation marks(") are required to use reserved words within an identifier.
For more info, please go through the below link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html